# Angular localstorage value visible as Plain text

Tags: angular, angular8, state-management

I have created an Angular website where i used localstorage to store data so that i can check if the user is logged in before accessing some pages. i have stored username in localstorage like this.

```
localStorage.setItem('username', this.username);
```

The Problem is that after i checked my website after publishing. The values stored in localstorage is visible as a plain text in the Application tab of Inspect Section.
[image: inspect section]

So, is there some workaround to prevent this. if not can you suggest any other simple method to check if the user is logged in.

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('username', this.username);` you are only storing username, so it will be plain text only. What is your exact requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For web application authentication the best practice is generating an `token` using [JWT](https://jwt.io/) and put the `username` inside the token which is in `hashed` for and is not visible. So you set the `token` into `localStorage`. Although, there are many secure way rather than `localstorage` such as `httpOnly`.

> If you need to store sensitive data, here's how to do it:
>
> - When a user logs into your website, create a session identifier for    them and store it in a cryptographically signed cookie. If you're
>   using a web framework, look up “how to create a user session using
>   cookies” and follow that guide.
> - Make sure that whatever cookie library your web framework uses is    setting the httpOnly cookie flag. This flag makes it impossible for a
>   browser to read any cookies, which is required in order to safely use
>   server-side sessions with cookies. Read Jeff Atwood's article for
>   more information. He's the man.
> - Make sure that your cookie library also sets the SameSite=strict    cookie flag (to prevent CSRF attacks), as well as the secure=true
>   flag (to ensure cookies can only be set over an encrypted
>   connection).
> - Each time a user makes a request to your site, use their session ID      (extracted from the cookie they send to you) to retrieve their
>   account details from either a database or a cache (depending on how
>   large your website is)
> - Once you have the user's account info pulled up and verified, feel     free to pull any associated sensitive data along with it

For more information read this article:
**[Please Stop Using Local Storage](https://dev.to/rdegges/please-stop-using-local-storage-1i04)**

Answer (score 1):

your implementation is completely wrong. if you want to store the data in local storage, you must use JWT. it means that you should post the username and password to the backend and they use libraries to change username and password to the encrypted format of them. then they return the value and after these procedures, you can store data in the local storage and the value is some characters that they are meaningless.

if you want to read more about JWT, you can visit [here](https://jwt.io/).

I hope it is working for you.